# how do I create vendor login page and access it through a special URL in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new in magento. I wanted to add multi vendor website in magento. how can I add multiple stores in magento and where do I can create a login form for vendors
 and also how can I add a URL for vendor login..for e.g.- abc.com/vendor instead of abc.com/admin

Answer (score -1):

You can create stores by following [this link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html).

and for second question, you can create multiple users by going through System->Permission->Users and click on Create User. You can restrict the access to the menu for the different users through by creating different roles to them through system->Permission-> roles and all of them ca be accessed through the same link